# How do I say "It's good to be curious about many things"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do you say "It's good to be curious about many things" in German?

> Es ist gut, neugierig über vieles zu sein.

Comment: Which dictionary has led you to believe that „neugierig über“ is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Es ist gut, vielfältige Interessen zu haben / an vielem interessiert zu sein.

It's not a fixed expression in German, though (that I am aware of).